# python insert indexerror: list index out of range

Tags: python

I am now saving images in order by 1...10
My first code was below.

```
save_path='/home/imagefolder'
for i in range(1,11):
    name=i
fullname=os.path.join(save_path,str(name)+".png")
```

But in this code, The image file is just saved only "9.png".

So I changed the way.

```
name=[]
fullname=[]
for i in range(1,11):
    name.insert(i,i)
    fullname=os.path.join(save_path,str(name[i]+".png")
    img.save(fullname[i])
```

And now, there is a indexerror: list index out of range.

I need help. please.

Comment: Has your question been sufficiently addressed? If so, you should mark the best answer with the checkbox to the left.

Answer (score 0):

Python is zero-indexed. Your insertions are indeed at the end of the list, but you retrieve them incorrectly because `1, 2, 3` are at positions `0, 1, 2`. The quickest fix would be to define `name` differently—not an empty list:

```
name = [None]  # Or any other arbitrary value
```

This way, there's something at index 0 that never gets used, but lets you insert 1 at index 1, then 2 at 2, and so on.

---

This may reveal another error in your code. You're missing a closing parenthesis on the line `fullname=os.path.join(save_path,str(name[i]+".png")`, which may just be a mistake in copying it over. Make sure the parenthesis is after `name[i]` like this:

```
fullname = os.path.join(save_path, str(name[i]) + ".png")
```

**Edit:** Since your code does run, that parenthesis must be somewhere. Please edit your question to show us where it is.

Comment: @Arya McCarthy  - thanks for your help. I fixed it according to your advice, but now the 10 image files are created at once. could you help me more?

Comment: What do you mean, they're "created at once"?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your first way may have been because the last line is not tabbed in fully:

```
save_path='/home/imagefolder'
for i in range(1,11):
    name=i
    fullname=os.path.join(save_path,str(name)+".png")
```

But the problem with your second way is that you are trying to insert something at index `1` when there is nothing in the list. To fix this, do:

```
name=[]
fullname=[]
for i in range(10):
    name.insert(i,i+1)
    fullname=os.path.join(save_path,str(name[i]+".png")
    img.save(fullname[i])
```

Or initialize `name` with something, like `name=[0]`.

Comment: thanks for your help. but your first way's result is same as before. and in second way, there is a key error. would you please fix the code more?

Answer (score 0):

You can add numbers (from 1 to 10) to your string like the below examples:

method1:

```
name=[]
string="img"
for i,j in enumerate(range(10),1):
    name.append(string+str(i))
print(name)
# Output -> ['img1', 'img2', 'img3', 'img4', 'img5', 'img6', 'img7', 'img8', 'img9', 'img10']
```

method2:

```
name=[]
string="img"
n=1
for i in range(10):
    name.append(string+str(n))
    n += 1
print(name)
# Output -> ['img1', 'img2', 'img3', 'img4', 'img5', 'img6', 'img7', 'img8', 'img9', 'img10']
```

method3:

```
name=[]
string="img"
n=1
for i in range(10):
    name.insert(n,string+str(n))
    n +=1
print(name)
# Output -> ['img1', 'img2', 'img3', 'img4', 'img5', 'img6', 'img7', 'img8', 'img9', 'img10']
```

method4:

```
name=[]
string="img"
for i,j in enumerate(range(10),1):
    name.insert(i,string+str(i))
print(name)
# Output -> ['img1', 'img2', 'img3', 'img4', 'img5', 'img6', 'img7', 'img8', 'img9', 'img10']
```

In your first code: you wrote:

```
save_path='/home/imagefolder'
for i in range(1,11):
    name=i
fullname=os.path.join(save_path,str(name)+".png")
```

But this is not a correct typing: try to write your codes as the below.

```
save_path='/home/imagefolder'
fullname = []
n=1
for i in range(10):
    fullname.append(os.path.join(save_path,str(n)+".png"))
    n += 1
print(fullname)
# ['/home/imagefolder\\1.png', '/home/imagefolder\\2.png', '/home/imagefolder\\3.png', '/home/imagefolder\\4.png', '/home/imagefolder\\5.png', '/home/imagefolder\\6.png', '/home/imagefolder\\7.png', '/home/imagefolder\\8.png', '/home/imagefolder\\9.png', '/home/imagefolder\\10.png']

#or use the below one.

save_path='/home/imagefolder'
fullname = []
for i,j in enumerate(range(10),1):
    fullname.append(os.path.join(save_path,str(i)+".png"))
print(fullname)
# ['/home/imagefolder\\1.png', '/home/imagefolder\\2.png', '/home/imagefolder\\3.png', '/home/imagefolder\\4.png', '/home/imagefolder\\5.png', '/home/imagefolder\\6.png', '/home/imagefolder\\7.png', '/home/imagefolder\\8.png', '/home/imagefolder\\9.png', '/home/imagefolder\\10.png']
```

Comment: would you please write full code? I fixed the code according to your code, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I need to edit the message because i must show with your codes.

Comment: thanks for your kindness. but where should i put "img.save(fullname)? when I put it in for loop, 10 image files are saved at once. and when I put it out of for loop, it is just formed "10.png". I think i have a problem when i save image.

Comment: sorry, it isn't changed. this is the front code of mine.   ps=self.__canvas.postscript(colormode='color')
img=PIL.Image.open(io.BytesIO(ps.encode('utf-8'))) is the problem occured because of that? I really don't know why it doesn't active.

Comment: I don't know which codes did you mention? The last codes that i wrote or different codes?. With the last codes i wrote: fullname contains 10 images. Try to copy the codes and test them.  And put the img.save(fullname) out of the for loop, for example under the print statement. Because as you can see print() function is out of the loop and print the 10 images folders.

Comment: I want to save image one by one whenever i clicked image. by any chance, did i explain what i want too be confused??

Comment: But i really don't know the other parts of the codes, what you want to do with this codes. So i suggest you to ask a new question which is not about index error. I think with the codes that i wrote, the index error problem is solved, is that so?

Comment: I am sorry to bother you. I will ask new question. thanks a lot.

Comment: No, you didn't bother me. But i think the other problems should be asked in different posts. Hope you will do as you please.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `KeyError` because the `list` is empty and you can't assign to a specific `index` when the `list` is empty. To fix that you can initialize the `list` with `None` values for example, then replace them when `looping`:

```
name = [None] * 11  # initialize the list with None values
```

and in the loop use:

```
name[i] = i
```

for example:

```
name= [None] * 11
fullname=[None] * 11
for i in range(1,11):
    name[i-1] = i
    fullname[i-1] = os.path.join(save_path,str(name[i-1])+".png")
    img.save(fullname[i-1])
```

Although, you have to start from index 0 so `name[i-1] = i` is better. Or you can just use `name.append(i)` since it will append in the same order as your for loop.

Comment: would you please write the full code? I don't know how to apply it.